# JObject to Integer and Integer to JObject

Tags: delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Does anyone know how to convert a `JObject` that was returned from `android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics.get()` to an `Integer` and also how to convert an `Integer` back to a `JObject` in Delphi.

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When requesting a `Key` whose type is a Java [`Integer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html), type-cast the returned `JObject` interface to `JInteger`, and then you can call its [`intValue()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue()) method.

To assign a Delphi `integer` to a `JObject`, use the `TJInteger.JavaClass.init()` or `TJInteger.JavaClass.valueOf()` method, both of which take a Delphi `Integer` as input and return a `JInteger` interface, which you can then type-cast to `JObject`.